# Weird IPython ipdb behaviour

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

I have some really weird behaviour that I just don't understand and therefore cannot explain, so I hope someone here can help me out. First thing I noticed was ipdb not letting me define variables any more:

```
ipdb> what=5
ipdb> what
*** NameError: name 'what' is not defined
whatelse=6
```

And a bit later I found ipdb returning this on my input (after running the code again):

```
dir()
ipdb> ['args', 'content_type', 'function', 'ipdb', 'item_code', 'kwargs', 'object_id', 'request', 'ud_dict', 'update_querydict', 'what', 'whatelse']
what=5
ipdb> what
5
ipdb> whatelse=7
ipdb> whatelse
ipdb> 6
whatelse
ipdb> 7
whatelse
ipdb> 6
whatelse
ipdb> 7
```

To me this looks as I have two interleaving debug sessions, which I have access to in some strange alternating pattern. How can I get rid of that?

**edit:**
Killing all python processes and re-running the code did help. Everything is back to normal now. But as I just don't understand what was going on, I would be very interested in an answer to what happened, and how to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: maybe those variables are in the scope already? I had the same problem today. When I was trying to assign to a variable p, but later upon choosing some other name, it worked fine. From what I understand I think the ipdb tries to have all the variables in scope of all related python processes running, so any conflict raises an error.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the variables are on scope, otherwise Python just could not access them. But what it looks like there are two different scopes in this case, which are accessed in an alternating pattern.

Comment: @marue, I notice this question was originally asked in 2012, but now has a bounty in 2014. Is this a recurring problem in need of a *specific* resolution to what is triggering it, or is it more of a "how can something like this happen"?

Comment: @mhlester I'm not in need of a specific solution, as you can see in my questions edit i could bring back normal behaviour by stopping all Python processes. I guess it's more of an academic question then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have two processes each consuming `stdin`, they can cause symptoms very similar to what you've described.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('python', shell=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000000001DEFEB8>
>>> Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 18:02:59) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> a = 5
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> a
5
>>> a = 6
>>> a
5
>>> a
6
>>> a
5
>>> a
6
>>> a
5
>>> a
6
```

The first time I called `a`, it was undefined, even though I'd defined it in the line above. I call it again and it's 5. Then I set it to 6, and each subsequent call alternates between the two. This seems to be exactly what you're experiencing.

`stdin` is line-buffering, causing *alternating lines* of text to pass to alternating processes, in this case two instances of Python.

Comment: Wow, pretty wheird. Not exactly what i was experiencing though. Just tried it, and the pattern is not exactly alternating but somewhat random. Still pretty amazing...

Comment: Can you show me output where it's non-random? Your q had `whatelse` alternating 6/7/6/7

Comment: Hm, i'm on Python 2.7.5 and do not get the same behaviour as you in your answer. On my machine Python just swallows some of my input. I enter "a" and nothing shows up, i enter a second "a" still nothing happens, i enter a third "a", press enter, Python says a is not defined. I press enter again - "aa is not defined". So what, your answer is pretty close, i think what i was experiencing was really two processes trying to grab the input. Thanks for your efforts.